# Get all Image Elements within a Grid->Canvas using LINQ?

Tags: linq, image, canvas, grid

i'm using a Grid within my Application which Contain some Canvas Elements which Contain some Images or Textblocks.

e.g.:

```
<Grid>
  <Canvas>
    <Image />
    <Image />
  </Canvas>
  <Canvas>
    <Textblock />
    <Textblock />
  </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Now i need to get all Image Elements within the Grid. 
Currently i'm using several foreach loops and if-statements to achive this. But i was asking myself if there isn't a more elegant way using LINQ so fetch all Image Elements from the Grid. But unfortunely my LINQ Knowledges aren't that well so i didn't found a way to get the to the Children of the Canvas Element.

Maybe someone has a good Solution to this.

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Kornelis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a Name to the Grid to reference in the link

```
<Grid Name="MyGrid">
```

Then this linq returns Images inside of canvases that are children of the Grid. I cast it as an object so that it could query every control that was in the Children collection.

```
IEnumerable<Image> results = (from c in MyGrid.Children.Cast<Object>()
                                where c.GetType() == typeof(Canvas)
                                select c).Cast<Canvas>()       
     .SelectMany(r => r.Children.Cast<object>()
     .Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(Image))).Cast<Image>();
```